# what happens to sql server if the active directory server goes down?

Tags: active-directory, sql-server

What happens to sql server if the active directory server goes down and the sql agent services is logged on as a windows user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will continue running, as its already authenticated.

Are you asking because you need to restart an AD server, or has your one and only AD server failed?

Comment: Yes the one and only AD server would be down for an hour and i am trying to understand the effects that the sql agent services would have on sql server. Would there be excessive error logging/any other effects?

Comment: Since the agent is authenticated, jobs should run without issue.